# what is $(h,k)$ supposed to be in coordinate geometry

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

I was doing some math questions and had difficulty answering any question that had $(h,k)$ in it I would highly appreciate it if you could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

h and k are simply variables used to refer to a point in two dimensional geometry function.. They have the same function as x and y in algebra.

A relation between h and k helps us to find the locus of a moving point. If one of the coordinates depends on the other, then the point for different values of the variable ( the variable servers as a parameter) will trace out a definite path which is called the locus.

Comment: I've never seen $(h,k) $ used for a varying point like a locus. Can you name a textbook/other reference that does that?

Comment: The elements of coordinate geometry by S.L Loney

Comment: I'm surprised to find it there, and it doesn't appear to be done in the chapter introducing loci, but they do use $(h,k)$ like that in examples like "102. Ex. The base of a triangle is fixed; find the locus of the vertes when one base angle is double of the other." I still suspect this is uncommon, especially among textbooks of the past 50 years.

Comment: I'm not sure about this but one of my teachers told me that different countries use different notation for representing loci. I prefer simply to leave them in terms of x and y. I come from India however and people here normally use h and k to represent loci. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

$(h,k)$ is a point whose horizontal coordinate is a number represented by the variable $h$ and whise vertical coordinate is represented by $k $. $(h,k) $ is usually used for a special point (like the center or vertex of graph) when the variable names $x $ and $y $ are being used for something else, like the coordinates of an arbitrary point on the graph.

Comment: can you tell me how to find them

Comment: @Andy That depends on the context: both the curve (a circle? A parabola? Half a hyperbola?) as well as what info you have (a picture? an equation? Etc.) and what techniques you learned in your course for finding them (factoring by completing the square? Memorizing a formula for the vertex of a parabola derived in class? Memorizing the horizontal coordinate but rederiving the vertical one on the fly?). I would recommend posting a new question with an exact problem statement, what you've found in your notes/textbook on the subject, and what you've thought about and tried